# MVC3 :: Navigate table from details view instead of clicking details links in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

I have an Index view that displays a list of items in a table.
Each item has a link to display its details (another partialview loaded via Ajax, replacing the index view).

Once clicking the details link, the user now wants to see details for the "Next Item" or "Previus Item". We currently have a back link that gets the index view again... and the user could click on any item... but what she wants is more usability.

As the list of items could have been filtered, I think the only way to achieve this is via jQuery or plain JS.

I was thinking on having some hidden field where I store all the item's IDs... stored not in the Index view (it goes away once accessing details) to be able to access it from the details and create the Back Next links. But its feels dirty... and a list of just IDs is not enought because I should track which is the current one in order to see which are the Next and Previous item. So... may be a JSON could do the trick.

**Any advice or other ways to store a list in client side?** The list could have from 10 to 200 items, that will be refreshed once I filter the index view again or by some other event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple approaches I could see.

1. Like TheZuck said, instead of navigating to the details page, use a Dialog or Modal window whose content is the details page. With this, you can use JavaScript to access the values from the Index page when the user wishes to navigate. I'm not as big a fan of this idea as it ties your navigation logic to rendered view content that could change.
2. You could keep the ids you need from the index page and pass them through to the details page. The upshot to this is it'd be a relatively minor bit of code to change for you. On the downside, you'd be posting and retrieving these ids with every navigation request.
3. You could do like #2 but with the addition of splitting your navigation controls from the details content itself. If you push the details into a partial view, you can now wire your navigation controls using AJAX helpers. Clicking forward would take you to the next id in your local list by issuing a POST or GET to an `ActionResult` in your controller that would return the partial view bound to the data for that id. I like this method most because it doesn't roundtrip the ids with each details navigation and doesn't require a lot of custom javascript to access ids from a rendered page. It gives you the opportunity to use a loading panel as well in case retrieving your data takes some time to retrieve.

An aside: if you really do not like storing your ids in a hidden input field or javascript variable or list, you can always make use of the `Session` but be careful if you're in a load balanced environment without sticky sessions. This way you have server-side access to the current filtered result. Your navigation requests would just send the current ID and the desired direction to navigate. In your controller, just pull the session, look up the ID and move your pointing forward or back (be careful to wrap-around or else make sure you have a way not to render a navigation button that would cause the wrap).

Of the choices, I like #3 the best for best UX especially if the details would be too large to render nicely in a small Modal or Dialog as in option #1. It can be the most responsive as well and, assuming you apply the aside, you have access to POCO representation of your list rather than serializing and deserializing in JavaScript. I would consider #1 if the Details page is so minor that it would easily fit into a Dialog or Modal window. It can be just as responsive as option #1, and you can still use the aside to keep from manipulating the ids in JavaScript.

The only reason I down-prioritize option #3 is because our UX person constantly denies client requests for "pop ups" that display the data. She hates them. I haven't figured out if it's personal or because UX best practices inform this decision but that's something I've never excelled at so I have no interest in finding out!

Answer (score 1):

well, you could display an overlay of the details instead of replacing the index view, in which case when the user clicks prev / next, you'd tell the index view layer: "listen, i'm showing x, but the user wants to see x+1, so please replace me with x+1"